# Trouble Running My First Simple Selenium Script

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, automation

```
package demoPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 

public class Seleniumscript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/newman/automation/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.apple.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

This is my first attempt at using Java and Selenium. I have Java, Eclipse, Selenium, and Chromedriver all downloaded. I followed along with a tutorial on YouTube step for step as far as opening eclipse and creating a package named demoPackage, then created a class named demo to get things started. For some reason I cant seem to properly import the Selenium Jars. I made sure to include all Jars, even the ones in the Lib folder. When I run the script I get an error in the console saying "Module demo1 not found", and also its telling me "the type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver is not accessible" and it says "the type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible".

My first thought is that it may have to do with the file path in the setProperty method. Maybe its because I added the external Jars to Classpath instead of Modulepath.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it!

I have tried changing the file path to "/Users/newman/automation/chromedriver.exe" instead of
"/Users/newman/automation/chromedriver" but still not getting the script to run.

Ive also tried hovering over Webriver and Chrome so it would give me options to import them but that did not get the script to run either.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine, just put back the 'exe' extension.
Driver file without exe extension is for linux.

In project properties in Java Compiler section check JDK Compliance.

[image: JDK Compliance]

Comment: I figured it out! I just needed to remove the module-info.java file. Once I removed that everything worked just fine. Thank you for your assistance!